# How to use more than one ace:fileEntry tag in the same page?

Tags: icefaces, icefaces-3

I have a page that should contain two `ace:fileEntry` tags: one to upload an audio file and another to upload an image file. The page should also have a save button. When clicking on the save button, I want to check if both an audio file and an image file are selected to be uploaded.

How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jforum.icesoft.org/JForum/posts/list/21126.page

Here is where this question is being responded to on the ICEfaces forums.